# help Icon is scrolling with the page

Tags: tooltip

I have a help icon when hover on the icon the text get displayed but it get hidden by the div to bring the info visible I added the css `position: absolute;` but adding this fix the issue and the info get displayed on the top of div. But the icon get stick to the screen and when the page is scrolled the icon start scrolling with the page. Do anyone have any solution to make the info popup display without any hiding but icon get not scroll with the page

Code

```
 <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 ActivityStyle">
                        <label class="myCustom slds-form-element__label noPaddingRight" style="margin-bottom:0rem; float:left;">
                            <span class="required " data-aura-rendered-by="97:188;a">*</span>
                            Activity
                        </label>
                        <!--c:CustomHelpTxt aura:id='Activitysuphelp' text="{!v.activityHelpMsgOld}" isNubbinbottom="true"/--> 
                        <span class="HelpTextAlignmentCSSWelkins">
                             <welkins_tooltip:WelkinsTooltip 
                                    helpText="{!v.activityHelpMsgOld}" 
                                    iconName="utility:info">
                             </welkins_tooltip:WelkinsTooltip>
                        </span>                                                             
                                                  
                        <span style="float:right" class="welkinstooltipWelkinsTooltip"> 
                            <aura:if isTrue = "{!v.activityHelpMsg}">                                    
                                <!--span class="HelpTextAlignmentCSSWelkins"--> 
                                    <welkins_tooltip:WelkinsTooltip  
                                        helpText="{!v.activityHelpMsg}" 
                                        iconName="utility:info">
                                    </welkins_tooltip:WelkinsTooltip>                        
                                <!--/span-->
                            </aura:if>
                            <aura:if isTrue = "{!v.fileId}">  
                                <!-- for DOWNLOADABLE FILE ONLY, CUSTOM LABEL NEEDED to store the Community BaseURL and will be changed in environments--> 
                                <a  href="{!v.cbaseURL+'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+v.fileId+'?operationContext=S1'}" style="display: inline-flex;"> 
                                    <!-- <a  href="{!'contentdocument/' +v.fileId}" target="_blank"> // for PREVIEW FILE ONLY --> 
                                    <!-- <a  onclick="{!c.openModal}"> //  for PREVIEW IN MODAL AND THEN SEE FILE --> 
                                    <lightning:icon class="slds-show" aura:id="addParams" iconName="standard:document" size="x-small" alternativeText="File" title="{!v.fileName}"/>
                                </a>
                            </aura:if>
                        </span>
```

[image: Browser Inspect]

[image: Before]

[image: After fix]

[image: New issue the icon get stick to the screen]

Answer (score 0):

1. add position:relative to the parent div
2. Also you can try to use z-index css property
3. Set z-index of the help text more than that of the card header